# Getting JSON object values by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a valid JSON object like this:

```
{
    "reasons": {
        "options": [
            {
                "value": "",
                "label": "Choose a reason",
                "selected": true,
                "requiresValidation": false
            },
            {
                "value": "small",
                "label": "Too little",
                "selected": false,
                "requiresValidation": false
            },
            {
                "value": "big",
                "label": "Too big",
                "selected": false,
                "requiresValidation": false
            },
            {
                "value": "unsuitable",
                "label": "I don't like it",
                "selected": false,
                "requiresValidation": true
            },
            {
                "value": "other",
                "label": "Other",
                "selected": false,
                "requiresValidation": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and I have a variable which stores one value (e.g. `unsuitable`) of an option available in `options`.
How can I retrieve the value of `requiresValidation` field for the value stored in the variable without having to loop through all of the objects values inside `options`?

For instance, if the var content is `other` I'd like to access to `requireValidation` field of the object whose value is `other` (which is `true`). Is it possible?
Thank you.

Comment: Either redesign the JSON to a different object structure or you will have to loop.

Comment: you don't deal with json directly. it's just a transport format. you convert the json back to a native data structure, then deal with the native structure only. e.g. decode the json to a javascript object, then it's just `obj.reasons.options[i].requiresValidation`

Comment: What is the justification for avoiding a for loop?

Comment: Thanks to @epascarello, redesigning JSON is the best trade-off.
Marc: I'd like to achieve the goal with no conversion.
Jason: it's just a matter of optimization. The real JSON is longer and inside the page I'd have to loop many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't really dealing with JSON here, you are dealing with a JS object.  JSON is just a format for sending JS objects.

`options` is an array.  The only way to access it is by index, which means you will have to do a search, one item at a time.  There are functions, such as `indexOf()` which will return the first index of a value in an array, however, you have an array of objects, so that will not work in this case.  (And internally, it is still doing a search).

```
function getReqVal(val) {
    for (var item in mydata.reasons.options) {
       if(item.value == val) {
           return item.requiresValidation;
       }
    }
}

getReqVal("other");
```

The caveat is that this will return on the first one, so if you have more than one `other`, you won't get them.

If the options are indeed unique values, I would rearrange your object to be an associative array, with the keys being the "value" items, and the values being an object with the rest of the data:

```
{
    "reasons": {
        "options": {
            "" : {
                "label": "Seleziona una voce",
                "selected": true,
                "requiresValidation": false
            },
            "small" : {
                "label": "Too little",
                "selected": false,
                "requiresValidation": false
            },
            "big" : {
                "label": "Too big",
                "selected": false,
                "requiresValidation": false
            },
            "unsuitable" : {
                "label": "I don't like it",
                "selected": false,
                "requiresValidation": true
            },
            "other" : {
                "label": "Other",
                "selected": false,
                "requiresValidation": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution for me at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

If you are (or could be) using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) you could use the [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) method:

```
var item = _.find(myObj.reasons.options, 
                  function(option){ return option.value == 'some value' });
```

Comment: FYI: _.find use a for cycle realisation in most common cases. Just look into underscore source code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't change the JSON structure itself (because perhaps you're getting it from an external source?), you can read it into a new object of your design per Marc B's suggestion. Ideally, this new object would let you index into your options array using the `value` key. Let's do that:

```
function MyOptions(optionsJSON) {
    this.original_json = optionsJSON;
    this.length = optionsJSON.reasons.options.length;
    var original_options = optionsJSON.reasons.options;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
       this[original_options[i].value] = original_options[i];
}

var my_opts = new MyOptions(original_JSON);

var item_requiresValidation = my_opts["unsuitable"].requiresValidation;
console.log(item_requiresValidation); // should log "true"
```

The trade-off here is that your code will need to loop through the entire options array once, but after that you can index into the objects using the `value` key without searching. Validate with [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/9JVfd/2).

Comment: A valid proposal, Austin!. I've opted for the solution submitted by Jeff B. since I could modify JSON structure a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use array filter. Some variation of this:

```
var $reasons = //Your JSON

function checkVal(element, index, array) {

    return (element.value == "other");
}

var filtered = $reasons.reasons.options.filter(checkVal);

alert(filtered[0].requiresValidation);
```

Or jQuery grep might help you with the filter without looping: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/