# select a value from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I was trying to follow this [Getting JSON object values by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122829/getting-json-object-values-by-name) but I can't get it.

My data comes from this JSON:
The green boxes show the values arrays and objets that I need to use.

http://fotos.subefotos.com/2a862e55595038ab73ab2f0805b83c15o.png

So I need to find the object inside the array "options" which has the id == 233 and then return it's "value", I'm trying to do it with this function:

```
function getReqVal(val) {
        for (var item in datos_puros[0].campos[0].campos[0].options) {
            if(item.id == val) {
               return item.value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm bringin the val like this:

```
getReqVal(datos_puros[0].campos[0].campos[0].value[0])
//console.log(datos_puros[0].campos[0].campos[0].value[0]) --> 233, it works
```

(datos_puros comes from an previous ajax call)

```
datos_puros = obj.estructura;
```

but I can't see where's my error. Please help

This is was I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/jrnfL9hp/1/

Comment: What result do you get now? Do you get a console error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: You expected the `for..in` loop to behave like a `for..of` loop. But it doesn't. That's one of the reasons you shouldn't use it to iterate arrays.

Comment: @musefan it's not entering the "if". I get this for (var item in datos_puros[0].campos[0].campos[0].options) {
                console.log(item.id); // undefined, undefined, undefined, ...
                console.log(item); // 1 ,2 ,3 ..., 51 (all the objects)
                if(item.id == val) {
                   return item.value;
                }
            }

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/jrnfL9hp/